# Adding new point on curve in CATIA V5 VBA

Tags: excel, vba, catia

I am writing VBA code for Catia V5 to define an endpoint on a reference line.

The section of code looks as follows:

```vb
Dim oReference1 As Reference
Dim oHybridShapeFactory As HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeFactory
Dim intPoint As HybridShapePointOnCurve
Dim oCount As Double
oCount = 10

LenVal = GetLengthValue(oPart, MessRef) 'LenVal stems from a function and is equal to 654.5 (for instance) of Type Double

Dim NoOfSections As Integer
NoOfSections = LenVal / oCount

Dim i As Double

For i = 0 To NoOfSections
     Set intPoint = oHybridShapeFactory.AddNewPointOnCurveFromDistance(oReference1, (i * (LenVal / NoOfSections)), False)
     ...
```

There is an error message on the `Set intPoint...` line stating:

> runtime error 91: object variable or with-block variable not defined

I have been digging through the help documentation. Everything seems to be defined as required - the Function *AddNewPointOnCurveFromDistance* takes a Reference, a double, and a boolean as *HybridShapePointOnCurve*.

Answer (score 1):

You define the objects but you don't set the object values.

So before you go into the loop...

```
'Set the HSF
Set oHybridShapeFactory = oPart.HybridShapeFactory
'Get the curve
Dim oCurve as HybridShape
Set oCurve = oPart.FindObjectByName("MyInputCurve") ' this is not the only way to get a curve object
Set oReference1 = oPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(oCurve)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I added the four lines of code you suggested immediately before the `For` loop but got the following error message on the `Set oReference1 = oPart.CreateRef....` line: **Runtime Error '-2147024809 (80070057)'; The method CreateReferenceFromObject failed**

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to correctly specify, the string name of the reference line in the "My Input Curve" snippet you send - by the looks of it appears to run through this section now!